# javascript function is not able to access private member of the object

Tags: javascript

My code is as shown below:

```
function Person (firstName,lastName,age){
    var firstName = firstName;
    var lastName = lastName;
    var age = age;

    function getName(){
        return firstName+ " " + lastName;
    }
}



var person = new Person("m","t",297)

print(person.getName())
```

When I run this code, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: person.getName is not a function
```

Comment: some javascript 101 for you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: use `this.getName = function(){...}`

Comment: Thats expected behaviour. Add getName to `this` in constructor function

Comment: you are not adding `getName` to the prototype of Person neither are you assigning `getName` to the `this` whenever `Person` is instantiated. Please get a book and read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing it with `this.getName`

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  var firstName = firstName;
  var lastName = lastName;
  var age = age;
  this.getName = function() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}



var person = new Person("m", "t", 297)

console.log(person.getName())
```

ALternatively you can add `getName`  to it's `prototype`

```js
function Person(firstName, lastName, age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;

}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
var person = new Person("m", "t", 297)
console.log(person.getName())
```

Answer (score 2):

use `console.log` instead of `print` and don't forget to attach functions to objects using `this.` notation

```js
function Person (firstName,lastName,age){
    var firstName = firstName;
    var lastName = lastName;
    var age = age;

    this.getName = function(){
        return firstName+ " " + lastName;
    }
}

 

var person = new Person("m","t",297)

console.log(person.getName())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct by using `this` so that your instance can get it's own params:

```
function Person (firstName,lastName,age){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;

    this.getName = function() {
        return this.firstName+ " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, for function constructors you use `this`:

```
function Person (firstName,lastName,age){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;

    this.getName = function(){
        return this.firstName+ " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
var me = new Person('m', 't', 297)
console.log(me.getName()) //'m t'
```

Second, get used to using ES6 classes:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, last, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.last = last;
    this.age = age;
  };

  getName() {
    return `${this.name} ${this.last}` //using ES6 string template literal
  }
}
```

I think your lacking basics, do personal research before asking on StackOverflow.